Laravel Markdown email
I am using Laravel markdown to send email to users.
The problem I am facing is when I tried to embed some HTML block inside an email.
I need to send HTML block in email, because I want to tell them know how to setup widget into their website.
If the HTML block is present, it is not rendered correctly.
How can I solve this?
:::Sample code:::
//Mailable class:

$greeting = Hi User;

$content = "
<div id="mainDiv" data-widget="main" data-code="{{$code}}"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain/js/main.js"></script>";

return (new MailMessage())
            ->subject($subject)
            ->markdown('email', [
                'greeting' => $greeting,
                'content' => $content
            ]);

//Template for email
@component('mail::message')
{{ $greeting }}

{!! $content !!}


Javascript in mails is not going to work. Most, if not all, modern mailclients will block this.
You can't mix and match HTML and Markdown e-mails, pick one.
Edit: On top of that, $greeting = Hi User; is not valid PHP, a string literal should be surrounded by ', ", or use heredoc/nowdoc syntax.
This code will cause a syntax error and will not proceed beyond that line.
If you fix that then your next error will be encasing HTML in " when also using " for it's attributes which wil also cause a syntax error.

There was some missing code. Some stuffs comes from variables like the user name. I fixed the content text as well.
If you put 3 spaces in before html block, then even html renders as string in as email.
All you have to do is {!! $content !!} in template. Cheers!!
